# Declaration of random packed associative array

Tags: associative-array, system-verilog

I wrote a code to initialize an packed associative array in the following fashion.

```
int              msize  = $urandom_range(20)            ;


bit  [0:3]      [0:msize]   mem     [int]               ;
```

But, it is showing error like : "Illegal operand for constant expression"
What is the alternative for this one.

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of the packed portion of an array must be a constant, decided at compile time. The assignment of `msize` is decided at run time. Make `msize` a parameter assigned at compile time.

**Alternatively**, if you want `mem` to have a random `msize` at run time, then `mem` should be defined as:

```
bit [0:3] mem [int] [];
```

Before accessing any element you should put:

```
if(!mem.exists(lookup_id)) mem[int_key_address] = new[msize];
```

Read all about arrays in SystemVerilog in § 7 of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html), it is free from IEEE the website.

Comment: Ok.
But parameter can not be initialized by using $random.
According to my problem statement, mem should be a packed array and size should be a random one.
So, it will be helpful if you have any other alternative.

Comment: The random `msize` scenario was the second part of my answer. Please re-read starting at the word "Alternatively" (now in bold).

Answer (score 0):

you can define the array as rand and use the constraint:

```
  rand msize    
  rand bit  [0:3] mem [int] []
```

then in a constraint:
      `msize inside [5:10]`
      `foreach(mem[idx])
      mem[idx].size == msize`
on a side note the seed used in $urandom is the different from the system verilog seed so if you use $urandom the test won't reconstruct